# Summary of Logistic Regression Model Showing Rows as Coefficients and Not Column Variables

Tags: r, arrays, logistic-regression

I have a clinical dataset which is made of subject IDs as rows and different variables as columns. I wanted to make a prediction model and split my data into testing and training data appropriately. I built a logistic regression model but for some reason the summary output for the fit is showing me the subject IDs as coefficients instead of the columns/variables.

**This is what the dataset looks like:**

```
subjectkey         sex   height      weight   interview_age flanker_score cardsort_score intbehaviour_score
NDAR_INV09AUXBBT    M   59.00000    104.00000     118           107          109            GOOD
NDAR_INV0BVP2PTD    F   50.25000    60.00000      120           92           103            GOOD
NDAR_INV0CV2Y4YR    M   55.30000    97.00000      120           83           94             BAD
NDAR_INV0X45NBYM    M   63.50000    104.50000     128           101          103            BAD
```

**This is the code I'm using to fit the model:**

```
data.train.glm <- glm(intbehaviour_score~., data = data.train, family = binomial)

#summary of fit
summary(data.train.glm)
```

**This is the output I'm getting:**

```
Call:
glm(formula = intbehaviour_score ~ ., family = binomial, data = data.train)

Deviance Residuals: 
  [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [34]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
 [67]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[100]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[133]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[166]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[199]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
[232]  0  0  0  0

Coefficients: (11 not defined because of singularities)
                             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)                -2.657e+01  3.561e+05       0        1
subjectkeyNDAR_INV0BVP2PTD -5.916e-13  5.036e+05       0        1
subjectkeyNDAR_INV0CV2Y4YR  5.313e+01  5.036e+05       0        1
subjectkeyNDAR_INV0X45NBYM  5.313e+01  5.036e+05       0        1
subjectkeyNDAR_INV10EP1VM2 -6.084e-13  5.036e+05       0        1
```

I don't understand why the subject IDs are coming up as the coefficients and not the variables.

Comment: I guess `intbehaviour_score~.` picks all variables including as `subjectkey` as predictors. You need to be more explicit with the right side of the `~`.

Comment: You're right, thanks so much!